# find the word and echo 100 character after it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have written the code bellow. I have a problem.
this code is for the 'Search' part of my website. when a word is searched, I want to have it found in all the texts over my website with 100 characters after that.
for example, when I search the word "universe", I want to have all the texts including this word with 100 characters after that:

("universe" existed mortally; human beings are born and they all naturally die at the end; the world has no creator and as a result, there is no... )

would you please tell me how to do so?

```
<div>
  <div class="title"><a  href="/html/Article/View/id/<?php echo $data['id']?>"><?php echo $data['title']?></a></div>
  <div class="description"><?php echo $description;?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you have tried yet ???

Comment: I think Stackoverflow is about giving specific answers to specific questions, rather than coding the whole stack solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following while printing your result

I assume `$description` is your whole content.

Use the following

`<?php echo substr($description,strpos($description,"universe"),100); ?>`

Let me know if it worked

Comment: thank you very much. It worked. but when I want to write like this method I get an error!  '.substr('.$data['description'].',strpos('.$data['description'].','.$info['title']).',100).'                                                                                                        "" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING""

Comment: please share the full code or at least this string concatenation line. I'll help you and give a upvote to my above answer so that it'll be helpful to someone also

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression to do that:

```
$text = 'xx universe12345678912345';
preg_match('/(universe.{0,100})/siu', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

returns string with optional up to 100 letters after that. You can grab more, and after that remove / close html tags